# Ruby: Check if string contains substring and nothing else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Users can upload a CSV file to my service. The CSV needs to have two column names and nothing else. One column needs to be "email" and the other "credit" and nothing else can be in those column names, no spaces, characters, returns, nothing.

Right now I'm getting the header with this:

```
first_row = File.open(csv_file.tempfile, &:readline)
first_row = first_row.downcase
```

So the first row is downcased and then checking for the existence of "email" or "credit" with this:

```
first_row.include?("email") && first_row.include?("credit")
```

Works great, until I realized it would pass the test even if the header contained other characters or spaces.. like this `email and pretty much anything else`

I was thinking of counting the length or splitting the string, but nothing I could come up with that would consistently determine if the `first_row` contained ONLY the words I need.

What do you all think?

Comment: Assuming you count the words and there are 2,  one is “email” and one is “credit” – isn’t that sufficient?

Comment: One option is to write `File.open(csv_file.tempfile, &:readline).chomp.match?(/\A(?:email,credit|credit,email)\z/i)`. [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/R0EOhP/1). [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/6yyUDaiKMYaZ0X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
first_row = File.open(csv_file.tempfile, &:readline)
first_row = first_row.downcase.strip
header = first_row.split(',')

if header.sort == ["credit", "email"]
  # The header is valid
else
  # The header is invalid
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```rb
CSV.parse(first_row, headers: true).headers - %w[email credit] == []
```

...or if you're happy (which you seem to be, despite your opening comments) with any case:

```rb
CSV.parse(row, headers: true, header_converters: :downcase).headers - %w[email credit] == []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Set#==`](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/set#method-i-3D-3D):

```rb
require "csv"
File.write("csv_file.csv", "Email,CRedit")

headers = CSV.table("csv_file.csv").headers.to_set
#=> #<Set: {:email, :credit}>
headers == [:credit, :email].to_set
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/stdlibs/csv/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Options%20for%20Parsing) documentation and use something along the lines of this to get the headers

```rb
headers = CSV.parse(row, headers: true).headers
```

If this is for testing, you would want to write something along the lines of:

```rb
let(:parsed_headers) { CSV.parse(row, headers: true).headers }
let(:expected_headers) { ['name', 'email'] }

it { expect(parsed_headers).to contain_exactly(expected_headers) }
```

If you are validating it in code, you can do something like:

```rb
REQUIRED_HEADERS = ['name', 'email'].freeze

def valid_headers?(headers)
  (headers & REQUIRED_HEADERS).size == required_headers.size
end
```

When both operands are arrays, the `&` operator will return the intersection of the two arrays. If you have two arrays -- one with known values and one with unknown values -- you can validate that the unknown value array contains the values in your known array if the size of their intersection equals the size of the known array. For example:

```rb
required = ['name', 'email']

intersection = ['a', 'b', 'email', 'c', 'name', 'd'] & required
=> ["email", "name"]
intersection.size == required.size
=> true

intersection = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'name', 'd'] & ['name', 'email']
=> ["name"]
intersection.size == required.size
=> false
```